# PHP exec | Null byte error when trying to set DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS

Tags: php, shell, unix, exec

I am building a CLI APP using PHP in which I need to send notifications using `notify-send` as a `root` user.

Now I know I need to set `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` before I try to send notification. otherwise it would not work.

Now this below code:

```
$c = sprintf("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=".$DBUS_SESSION." /usr/bin/notify-send \"TITLE\" \"MESSAGE\"");
system($c);
```

Throws an error

> system(): NULL byte detected. Possible attack in
>   /filepath.php on
>   line 186

from my extensive debugging I have found `$DBUS_SESSION` is causing the issue. However If I hard code the `$DBUS_SESSION` value then the command works without a problem!.

like this:

```
$c = sprintf("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus,guid=5ded8923178f8ea19642e36a5a37eb76 /usr/bin/notify-send \"sdfTITLE\" \"MESSAGE\"");
system($c);
```

What is going on here? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're directly passing the variable to sprintf, but that's not how it works. You dictate the argument type, then provide the variable in order as continued arguments to the sprintf function, like this:

```
$c = sprintf("DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=%s /usr/bin/notify-send \"TITLE\" \"MESSAGE\"", $DBUS_SESSION);
system($c);
```

This should solve the `NULL BYTE detected` error

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same error. I think the error is due to the type of string being passed. the `DBUS` contains something that is causing this issue